# Clarification on the proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma in Folland's Real Analysis: Why does $f\in C^1\cap C_c\implies\hat{f}\in C_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

This question concerns one detailthe given proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma in Folland's *Real Analysis - Modern Techniques and Their Applications* (2nd edition), pp. 249. The claim is that $\mathcal{F}\left(L^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)\right)\subset C_0\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$. The author begins the proof as follows:

> By e.), if $f\in C^1\cap C_c$, then $|\xi|\hat{f}(\xi)$ is bounded and hence $\hat{f}\in C_0$.

where the part e.) is

> If $f\in C^k$, $\partial^\alpha f\in L^1$ for $|\alpha|\leq k$, and $\partial^\alpha f\in C_0$ for $|\alpha|\leq k - 1$, then $\hat{\left(\partial^\alpha f\right)(\xi)} = \left(2\pi i \xi\right)^\alpha \hat{f}(\xi)$

and $C_c$ is the set of continuous functions with compact support and $C_0$ is the set of continuous functions vanishing at the infinity.

What I can't recall/grasp is that why does the Fourier transform of $f\in C^1\cap C_c$ vanish at infinity?

Comment: do you agree that $|\xi|\hat{f}(\xi)$ is bounded? If yes, then this is obvious; it implies $|\hat{f}(\xi)|\leq \frac{M}{|\xi|}$, where $M=\sup\limits_{\xi\in\Bbb{R}^n} |\xi||\hat{f}(\xi)|<\infty$. This inequality shows that as $\xi\to \infty$, $\hat{f}(\xi)\to 0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ah, of course. I suspected that I was missing something obvious. Thanks anyway!